# Undici mocking won't intercept my request in a jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, fetch

I am trying to upgrade my node project to use version 18 and the built in fetch vs our old method of using node-fetch.  We were writing tests using nock, which isn't an option with this version of fetch. I am not able to get undici to intercept the request.  I am getting the response as if I went to the page (google.com/test)

I created a standalone test file and that didn't work either.

```
const { MockAgent, setGlobalDispatcher, } = require('undici');
test('should respond with body passed in', async () => {
  const opts = { method: 'GET' };
  const body = { statusInfo: { status: 'SUCCESS' }};

  const agent = new MockAgent({ connections: 1 });
  agent.get('http://www.google.com').intercept({
    path: '/test'
  }).reply(200, body);
  agent.disableNetConnect();
  agent.activate();
  setGlobalDispatcher(agent);
  const result = await fetch('http://www.google.com/test', opts);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  // console.log('%o', result);
  console.log(await result.text());
  // expect(result).toEqual(body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, intercepting requests made with built-in fetch with undici MockAgent doesn't work in Jest. It's possibly caused by Jest overriding globals - [old problem of Jest](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/2549)

Check this issue https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1882 for details.

---

Your test will work as expected in e.g. Mocha or [Node.js test runner](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html). I don't know if you have an option of not using Jest but that's the only way currently to be able to use built-in fetch and intercept requests